# How to sort returned data from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort my items in the listview alphabetically, I tried `orderByChild("name")` but I don't think it even worked. However here's my code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference medicinesRef = rootRef.child("Medicines");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    medName = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", medName);
                    myArrayList.add(medName);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> firebaseAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MedicineSearch.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayList);
                    lv.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };      // populates listview
        medicinesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

        rootRef.keepSynced(true);
```

Comment: What data type is myArrayList?

Comment: It is a `String`

Comment: What about after you populate your String myArrayList with child elements, sort it and pass it to your listview

Comment: That's why I'm asking, how can I do it dude? Is it on the xml or the MainActivity?

Comment: use Collections.sort(yourList) . You can call Collections.reverse if needed later.

Comment: Yes, do it on your mainActivity. Should be something like this: Collections.sort(myArrayList); After your myArrayList has been populated and not equal to null.

Comment: These should be on answers lol. It worked perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to sort data, you need to use a `Query` and for that, please see the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference medicinesRef = rootRef.child("Medicines");
Query query = medicinesRef.orderByChild("name");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Another approach would be use the same code and to sort the list using:

```
Collections.sort(myArrayList);
```

But do not create and use the adapter inside the for loop. Move those two lines of code outside the loop, otherwise you end up having a single item in your `ListView`.